# Is there somewhere in Sydney, Australia where I can exchange unusual foreign currencies?

Tags: money, tips-and-tricks, exchange, sydney

I've got a bunch of Iranian Rials left over from a recent trip because I assumed, stupidly, that like other airports there'd be an exchange place after passport control. Sadly, that was not the case.

As a result, I'm stuck with a bit of IRR left over.  Travelex won't take it, and the couple of banks I've tried won't either.

[I asked a similar question about London a few years back](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/1596/101), with some success, so I'm hoping for similar results with Sydney...

Comment: Due to the sanctions against Iran you will find IRR difficult to exchange _anywhere_ outside Iran.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm hopeful with the recent treaty being signed that it might be feasible soon...

Comment: Just to let you know, if you trip was before the treaty then you are lucky as the exchange rates have spiked and you would make money once you find a place to exchange what you have

Comment: @User indeed, the treaty was announced  while I was in Iran :)

Comment: Find an Iranian restaurant, and see if they'll take them / one of their staff will change them?

Comment: @Gagravarr that's not a bad idea.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Are you saying that *everywhere* outside of Iran takes part in the sanctions?

Comment: @hippietrail There are UN sanctions, and separate US and EU sanctions. The _effect_ of these is that Iranian banks are not connected to global banking networks such as SWIFT, and foreign banks in Iran are rare, so it's quite difficult for foreign banks to repatriate Iranian currency. I'm not going to say it's _completely_ impossible; you might try your luck in Venezuela.

Comment: Would you accept Melbourne instead of Sydney?  Or Victoria?

Comment: @GayotFow not really, as I live in Sydney, although if you do actually know one in Melbourne, I could ask as separate question, as I head down there on occasion.

Comment: @MarkMayo, no please don't ask a separate question. It's better to chat it out first and if you think my tip is valuable I can add an answer here.  Or just leave it with you :)

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you mean by unusual.  If you specifically mean Iranian Rials, I think you're out of luck.  There doesn't appear to be any reputable money changers that will change them in Sydney, though I'm not excluding the prospect of finding some small and/or under the table money exchange business handling them in some areas of Sydney with an Iranian ex pat population, e.g. [Fairfield](http://fairfield.localstats.com.au/demographics/nsw/sydney/liverpool-fairfield/fairfield) or [elsewhere in western Sydney](http://lacextra.legalaid.nsw.gov.au/PublicationsResourcesService/PublicationImprints/Files/557.pdf).

If you mean more generally, here's a quick list of currencies that are exchanged by at least one provider, noting I only reviewed the major providers.  I'd consider plenty of these unusual but YMMV:

- Argentina
- Australia
- Bahamas
- Bahrain
- Bangladesh
- Barbados
- Bermuda
- Brazil
- Brunei
- Canada
- Cayman Islands
- Chile
- China
- Colombia
- Croatia
- Czech
- Denmark
- Domincan Republic
- Egypt
- Euro
- Fiji
- French Africa
- French Polynesia
- HK
- Hungary
- Iceland
- India
- Indonesia
- Israel
- Jamaica
- Japan
- Jordan
- Kenya
- Kuwait
- Madagascar
- Malaysia
- Mauritius
- Mexico
- Morocco
- Norway
- NZ
- Oman
- Pakistan
- Peru
- Phillipines
- PNG
- Poland
- Qatar
- Russia
- Samoa
- Saudi Arabia
- Seychelles
- Singapore
- Solomon Islands
- South Africa
- South Korea
- Sri Lanka
- Sweden
- Switzerland
- Taiwan
- Thailand
- Tonga
- Trinidad
- Tunisia
- Turkey
- UAE
- United Kingdom
- US
- Vanuatu
- Vietnam

Comment: Downvoted because MMDV greatly.