# Where in Switzerland can I exchange Nepalese Rupee into Swiss Francs?

Tags: money, switzerland, exchange, nepal

I have Nepalese rupees at home that are worth around 50 Swiss francs (45 Euros). I wanted to exchange them and tried two large banks. Both of them said that they don't accept Nepalese rupees. So what can I do to get Swiss francs for Nepalese rupees in Switzerland? I don't have any coins, just bills.

Comment: Did you tried Nepal embassy?

Comment: Have you tried Travelex? It has 'stores' in Basel, Weil and Zurich.

Comment: Might be of help: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1596/changing-unusual-foreign-currencies-in-london

Comment: And if you're totally stuck, you could try connecting with an [NGO](https://nepal.helvetas.org/en/about/partners/0) such as this. Team members heading there might be happy to do the exchange, in advance of their trip to Nepal.

Comment: Have you tried at SBB (http://www.sbb.ch/en/station-services/services/change-currency-exchange.html), they are selling NPR. I'm not sure if they are also buying your NPR. It is worth a try...

Comment: @LaurentG SBB Change offers an extremely poor exchange rate for Nepalese rupees. If you sell 100CHF worth of NPR, they will give you 74CHF. If you want to buy 100CHF worth of NPR, you have to pay 148CHF.

Comment: Have you tried at the airport money exchange services? Another discovery: you can [do it easily in Australia](http://www.anz.com/aus/RateFee/fxrates/fxpopup.asp), should you know someone travelling through.

Comment: Did you end up exchanging the cash?

Comment: Not yet :( I was at the airport twice so far, but both times the exchange services there wer already closed.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're okay with mailing your currency, you should try [Thomas Exchange in London](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1596/changing-unusual-foreign-currencies-in-london?noredirect=1&lq=1):

> Thomas Exchange will change almost any currency into Sterling -
>   including the Mongolian, Kazakhestan, Uzbekistan and Kyrgyzstan,
>   Armenian and Georgian currencies, and many other obscure currencies
>   and even pre-Euro currencies such as French Francs, Italian Lira, etc.
>
> We do not charge any additional fees and our rates are always better
>   than the Post Office, M & S, etc.
>
> If you wish to exchange the currencies, you can visit our Oxford
>   Circus branch at #5 Market Place, 2 minutes walk from Oxford Circus
>   tube Station.
>
> Alternatively, if you are based outside London, you can post the
>   currencies to us, and we can pay you by Cheque or deposit funds
>   directly into your bank account (note:  **please call us on 0207 493
>   1300 before you post**).  We usually recommend that you post the
>   currency to us by Royal Mail Special Delivery.
>
> Our address is:
>
> Thomas Exchange UK   5 Market Place   London   W1W 8AE
>
> Our website is: http://www.thomasexchange.co.uk (but not all our
>   currency rates are displayed on here).
>
> If you require any further info, contact Paul Nelson on 0207 493 1300.